# Heroku: rogue transfer in progress

Tags: heroku, migration, database-migration

I started a migration on Heroku last night that gave me no feedback for hours, and which I eventually stopped because it wasn't clear if the system was even doing anything.

Ever since, it's been a nightmare. I cannot access the relevant database tables in `heroku console`, I can't migrate, rollback, or use pgbackups.

Helpfully, pgbackups gave me a one line explanation just now:

```
a transfer is currently in progress
```

This I assume is the migration I tried to execute hours ago. How can I **stop** whatever Heroku is doing so I can do a quick restore and get back up and running?

Comment: You may have been affected by the Amazon outage, which in turn caused a Heroku outage. This happened about 20 hours ago.

Did `heroku restart` do any good?

Comment: `heroku restart` did nothing I'm afraid. My issue began about 8 hours ago so I don't believe Amazon is related.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can remove the problem backup stuck in the "a transfer is currently in progress" by finding the name of the backup and then destroying it. E.g.

```
heroku pgbackups
```

My problem backup was listed like this:

```
b210 | 2013/01/02 12:29.33 | unknown | DATABASE_URL
```

So to destroy it I just did:

```
heroku pgbackups:destroy b210
```

It removed the problem backup for me so I could get on with using pgbackups again properly.

Comment: Cunning - I don't think I'd have thought of that. It seems to have unblocked my problem too.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem too. Found an easier way of fixing it - briefly remove the pgbackups addon.

```
heroku addons:remove pgbackups
heroku addons:add pgbackups
```

**WARNING** as mentioned in the comments below, this will destroy all extant backups!

Comment: be careful with this, you will lose backups if you do so.

Comment: This is a dangerous answer!

Comment: True. I've edited the answer to make it clear that this is a destructive procedure.

Comment: People in a rush might still end up copying the answer and woops, it's too late. I don't find Will Tew's answer any more complicated, it's two commands too. I think the best thing is to delete this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally did a transfer from my `COLOR_URL` database to my `DATABASE_URL` which was the same database.  `heroku pgackups:transfer` let this happen which caused the main database to get stuck in

```
a transfer is currently in progress
```

I fixed it by looking at the process list `pg:ps` and killing all connections `pg:killall`
After doing this and looking at `pg:ps` the process list was empty and I was free to use the main database again with `pgbackups`.

NOTE this could be a destructive operation so make sure you have a snapshot before you do this.

Comment: This worked for me. FYI though: It seems to take a while for the process to die.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to contact Heroku support and have them kill the rogue process for you. They say they are re-architecting pgbackups to give users more control.

Answer (score -1):

It never became clear what happened - after a day or so I was able to interact with `heroku console`, but I was never able to run another migration. This is what I did:

1. Renamed my app to something else.
2. Created a new app in its place, checking the stack was the same, and copying over all add-ons and domains.
3. I restored the database from pgbackups (highly recommended if you're not using this add-on).

This fixed the problem. **Note:** Be careful to check that your pgbackup doesn't cause unacceptable data loss.

Comment: Give a reason for -1's please.

Comment: I think Will Tew's answer is the correct answer based on the question text. The question was about stopping a bad pgbackups transfer and his way of resolving the problem is much more direct. Will you consider to mark his answer as the correct answer instead?